# How to reference an input in SQL functions?

Tags: mysql, function

I have a table like this:

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

I am writing a function with mySQL to get the n th largest value in Salary.
Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    # Write your MySQL query statement below.
    select DISTINCT Salary 
    FROM Employee 
    ORDER BY Salary  DESC
    LIMIT 1 offset (N - 1)
    #FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    
  );
END
```

But I got the an error near (N-1).
[image]

if I change (N-1) to 1 :

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    # Write your MySQL query statement below.
    select DISTINCT Salary 
    FROM Employee 
    ORDER BY Salary  DESC
    LIMIT 1 offset 1
    #FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    
  );
END
```

It runs correctly.
So the question is how to reference input in SQL function? It seems it can be directly called as an argument as we do in other languages.

Comment: *I get the error* is not a problem description. What is the error you're seeing? What is the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: @KenWhite it seems to be a syntax error. It just says it's near (N-1). No other specific information...I am using the SQL panel on leetcode.

Comment: @KenWhite the error message has been attached. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I need to declare and set a variable before reference it in SQL query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE M INT;
SET M=N-1;
  RETURN (
    # Write your MySQL query statement below.
    select DISTINCT Salary 
    FROM Employee 
    ORDER BY Salary  DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET M
    #FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY 
  );
END
```

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT argument cannot be a variable. Use prepared statement - in it the LIMIT parameter may be taken from a variable. But dynamic SQL is not allowed in the function - use stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getNthHighestSalary(N INT)
BEGIN
    SET @sql := 'SELECT DISTINCT Salary 
                 INTO @output
                 FROM Employee 
                 ORDER BY Salary  DESC
                 LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?';
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    SET @output := N-1;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @output;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
    SELECT @output;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=740b1dfba067688fe1562f88837adf06)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, I am working on the leetcode problem, which requires me to write a function...But thanks anyway!